# Problem involving concentration of solution with inflow and outflow

Tags: fluid-dynamics, water

A question describes a tank, initially with 50L of pure water, with 2L of brine solution(at $5gmL^{-1}$) flowing in per minute, alongwith 1L flowing out per minute(the mixture's kept uniform by constant stirring). You're supposed to find the mass of salt in the tank, m, as a function of time t in minutes.

The equation used is this;
$$\frac{dm}{dt}=10-\frac{m}{50+t}$$
Everything else makes sense, but this; how can 'm' be used? This equation is written across the couse of one minute, during which the mass of salt in the tank changes. This equation treats it like there's m grams of salt in the tank for the full minute, which it doesn't look like there is.

How does the equation come about that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let Q be the volume flow rate of water into the tank, and let q be the volume flow rate of water out of the tank.  And let V the volume of fluid in the tank at any time.  Then $$\frac{dV}{dt}=Q-q$$ and thus $$V=V_0+(Q-q)t=50+t$$Let C be the concentration of salt in the liquid within the tank at any time.  Then, a mass balance on the salt gives:  $$\frac{d(VC)}{dt}=QC_{in}-qC$$If the total mass within the tank is $$m=VC$$then $$C=\frac{m}{V}$$If we combine the previous equations, we obtain $$\frac{dm}{dt}=QC_{in}-\frac{q}{V}m$$

Another approach would be to solve for the concentration.  From the salt mass balance, we have $$V\frac{dC}{dt}+C\frac{dV}{dt}=V\frac{dC}{dt}+(Q-q)C=QC_{in}-qC$$or $$\frac{dC}{dt}=\frac{Q}{V}(C_{in}-C)$$